# Probability of getting exactly 4 spades

Tags: probability

Six draws are made from an ordinary deck of playing cards, the card drawn being replaced and the deck thoroughly shuffled before the next draw is made. What is the probability of obtaining exactly $4$ spades?

Help me please i keep getting $\frac{9}{4096}$ 
but choices are

a.$\frac{135}{4960}$

b.$\frac{153}{4096}$

c $\frac{135}{4690}$

d.$\frac{135}{4096}$

Comment: Hint:  each drawn card is a spade with probability, independent of all other draws, of $\frac 14$.

Comment: Note:  your answer is obviously wrong.  The probability that the first four cards are all spades is greater than your value.  How did you compute it?

Comment: How do you get that numerator $9$? Note that the probability of getting exactly the configuration $--SSSS$ (with $S$ for spade, and a minus for an other color) is this $(3/4)^2\cdot(1/4)^4$. (Here extracting a spade in one step has the probability $1/4$.) But what about other places for the two minus signs? Please complete the path of thinking, best post your own answer!

Comment: i thought it would be ((13/52)^4) ((39/52)^2)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As yourself (@azylie) states, $(\frac{13}{52})^4(\frac{39}{52})^2$ that by simplification meets what @dan_fulea states, $(\frac{1}{4})^4(\frac{3}{4})^2$.

Now without changing denominator, that is $4096$, consider reduced problem that you has only ONE (instead of $13$) card of each types. Now you should $4$ times drawn spades ($1^4$), and $2$ times drawn others ($3^2$). Also you have $\binom{6}{2}=\binom{6}{4}$ to choose which ones be spades or others:
$$1^4.3^2\binom{6}{2}=135$$